# How to get what radio button was clicked in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am completely new to Meteor and I'm trying to build a simple app. I currently have a form with 4 radio options and a submit button. When users click the submit button and I want to know which radio option they selected. I have no idea how to get started though. Can anyone help me? Below is my html and javascript code, respectively:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal well mystery-form">
    <fieldset class="col-md-offset-1">
      <h2>{{question}}</h2>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10 mystery-form">
          {{#each answers}}
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="mysteryForm" checked="" 
                     style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;">
              {{answer}}
            </label>
          </div>
          {{/each}}
          <br>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
          <!-- Hide this when the answer is correct -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check Answer</button>
          <!-- Show only if the answer is correct -->
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

JS:

```js
Template.mystery.events({
"submit .mystery-form": function(event) {

 // no idea what to do here

}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Semantics

You'll probably want to remove the whole wrapping `.radio` element. It's unnecessary. Try using as few elements as possible. It performs better and makes debugging easier.

### Retrieving the checked `input`

The event object passed to an [event-map](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) callback has a property `target`. In your case that is `.mystery-form`. So you can use a simple jQuery selector to find the checked element:

```
$('input[name="mysteryForm"]:checked', event.target)
```

This will get you the checked value with the name `mysteryForm`. This was quiet straight forward. The problem is retrieving the value. Doing that would get sort of messy. So I'd just pass it to the element as a `data-` attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="mysteryForm" checked="" style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;" data-answer="{{ answer }}" >
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
$('input[name="mysteryForm"]:checked', event.target).data('answer')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to prevent the normal form submission and avoid a page reload. As you are building a single page application you will want to do the form submission logic by yourself. Also, reloading the page by form submission does not make any sense in such application.

Secondly, you have to actually gather the data, and then do what you want with these data.

Put it all together and you get something like this:

```
Template.mystery.events({
  "submit .mystery-form": function(event, template) {

    //1. prevent default behavior (form submission)
    event.preventDefault();

    //2. get your data
    //either by name (HTML name attribute)
    var inputValue = template.mysteryForm.value;
    //or by id (HTML id attribute)
    var inputValue = template.find('#myId').value;

    //3. Do whatever you want (method call for example?)
    Meteor.call('myMethod', inputValue, function(error, result) {
      //wait for the call result...
    });
  }
});
```